# How to convert 3 digit 24 hour time to 12 hour clock with joda-time?

Tags: java, android, datetime

Is it possible to convert a 3 digit time to HH:mm a format using joda time?  I've tried the following

```
int databaseTime = cursor.getInt(TIME);
DateTimeFormatter worldTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmm");
String localTime = worldTime.parseDateTime(databaseTime);
```

This works great for any time in the database above 1000, but errors out if the time out of the database is 100-900 (0100-0900) with an error such as "70 is not an hour" or something (not smart enough to figure out that 700=0700).

So then I tried

```
String dbTime = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(Globals.CLASSTIME));
String nextClassTime = (dbTime.length() < 4) ? "0" + dbTime : dbTime;
DateTimeFormatter worldTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmm");
DateTimeFormatter normalTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime wt = worldTime.parseLocalTime(nextClassTime);
String lt = normalTime.print(wt);
```

But this prints the "Local time" as "07:00 AM"

Is there a way to get it to return "7:00 AM"?  I suppose one possible solution is to turn my database time into a String, instead of an integer, and then save 3 digit times with the preceeding 0, but I'd like to not touch the database if possible (this would require editing my webservices as well)

Comment: Try `"H:mm"` and check.

Comment: Or "Hmm" as there's no indication that there's a colon. It may well still fail to do the right thing though, depending on the implementation. (I know Noda Time would.)

Comment: will the H:mm a still account for "10:00 AM" / "10:00 PM"?  let me try it

edit: works!  @TheNewIdiot can you post as an answer so i can accept it, and then upvote Snicolas for the recommendation on SQL Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@The New Idiot is right, the [docs of Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) state that

> Shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount.

So "h" only should be padded whereas "hh" will not.

Also, you should consider using a long for storing time, more than int. SQL Date is also a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.   If @TheNewIdiot doesn't post his answer as a solution, I'll mark yours as accepted.  I knew it was something stupid, but I couldn't find the ISO format section in the Joda API guide to remember the differences between H, hh, HH, etc..

Comment: accepted this since the first guy never posted his answer as an answer.  Thank you all!